# Pass JavaScript to @Html.Actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass JavaScript value into `@Html.ActionLink("Sửa", "EditShopping","Home",{Id=})` where Id is passed from JavaScript

Pieces of detail code as below(dataTable plugin jQuery):

```
{
  "bSearchable": false,
  "bSortable": false,
  "mData": 0,
  "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
      return '@Html.ActionLink("Sửa", "EditShopping", "Home", new {Id=})';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
var YourId='1';
var url = '@Url.Action("EditShopping", "Home")';

url = url + "?Id="+ YourId;

{
  "bSearchable": false,
  "bSortable": false,
  "mData": 0,
  "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
      return '<a href="'+url+'">Link</a>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, Ehsan Sajjad.

Comment: you are welcome @vduman, mark it answer if it worked for you, and you can vote up as well, if you want..:)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed to @Html.ActionLink will be finally added to the query string parameter by MVC.

You can add the query string value with the original url like below

```
"mRender": function (data, type, full) 
{
  return '@Html.ActionLink("Sửa", "EditShopping", "Home")'+'?Id='+YourJSVariable;
}
```

Comment: @vmduan, Why it wont work? For your code the url should be `/EditShopping/Sửa?Id=2`. Please make sure the url is perfect

Comment: Thanks Murali Murugesan, but it show 'Sửa?id=2' with 'Sửa' is link map with <a href="/Home/EditShopping" value="Sửa"/>